# Android List View remove all items

Tags: java, android, listview

How can I remove all items in my ListView? I have custom adapter and I run this code to remove all the items, but it's not working:

```
friendList = new ArrayList<FriendRow>();
//Later i call this to remove all the items.
friendList.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Try `myListView.setAdapter(null)`

Comment: Actually, this solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `myListView.setAdapter(null)`.

Answer (score 1):

Changes to the UI need to be done on the UIThread. Calling notifyDataSetChanged() won't work unless it's called on the UIThread. You could try adding something like:

```
public void clearAdapter()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        friendList.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    };
}
```

and then calling clearAdapter() when you want to clear it.